# How to Make ImageView Scroll Endlessly

Tags: objective-c, swift

How can I make this `imageview` scroll endlessly, where the `imageview` repeats itself where the next imageview trails the first one?

This code loops the imageview: `foodbg` once, but i'd like for it to loop endlessly:

```
// set up some constants for the animation
    let duration : NSTimeInterval = 5.0
    let delay : NSTimeInterval = 0.0
    let options = UIViewAnimationOptions.CurveLinear

    // create the background imageview and add it to the screen
    let foodbg = UIImageView()
    foodbg.image = UIImage(named: "foodbg5.png")
    foodbg.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height)
    self.view.addSubview(foodbg)


    var endBackgroundScroll: Bool = false
    // define the animation
    UIView.animateWithDuration(duration, delay: delay, options: options, animations: {
        // move the background
        foodbg.frame = CGRectMake(0, self.view.frame.size.height, self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height)
        }, completion: { animationFinished in
            // remove the background
            foodbg.removeFromSuperview()
    })
```

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/StreetScroller/Introduction/Intro.html

Comment: I looked through that but had some trouble because it does not use swift.

Comment: it shows the concept, actually, and the concept is the same for Swift as well.